# Firefox storage API : basic data save not saving

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm working on my first Firefox extension. I'm trying to save data in the local storage of my browser (which was easy enough using `Window.localStorage`, but I'm following [official recommandations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage)).

My class has a `save` method that looks like that.

```
static save(content) {
  const setCurrent = browser.storage.local.set({ current: content });

  setCurrent.then((result) => {
    console.log('saved')
  }, onError);
}
```

When it's called I get the 'saved' console.log, but when I look in the 'storage' tab of Firefox developpers tools, I see that nothing is saved. I don't know how to debug that.

Comment: How are you trying to retrieve the data from storage?

Comment: By looking in the 'storage' tab of Firefox developpers tools. I made a previous attempt with `Window.localStorage` and it was wotking fine.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the FF devtools but I would have thought an extension's storage is only accessible via the storage API.

Comment: In the official documentation, you can find the following sentence : 'You can examine the stored data under the Extension Storage item in the Storage Inspector tab of the developer toolbox'. It's supposed to work.

Comment: Make sure you are actually on a page with the moz-extension origin. Try going to about:debugging > This Nightly > "Your Extension" > Inspect then click on the "Storage" tab > "Extension Storage".

Comment: @evilpie I just tried again, nothing there.

Comment: @evilpie I tried once again, and I found my data. thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @evilpie I found the solution. The data was available in 'Extension storage' tab and not in the 'local storage' one. Which is present only in the about:debugging toolbox, and not on the classic developper toolbox.

I was misled by my first try. When you use the `Window.localStorage` API, you can find all the data in any tab, in 'local storage'.